# Small eps figure size in Matlab

Tags: matlab, figure, eps

How to create a small eps file from a Matlab figure? I use LaTeX and the eps that I'm getting with Matlab (R2010a) is of the order 6 MB. How to set the plot options to give an eps figure of smaller size?

Does the render options painters or zbuffer help?

Thanks a lot...

One additional info: I use Laprint to generate my eps figures. So, I end up with 2 files: 1 tex file with information about the labels etc and one eps file which is just for the drawing itself. I use Laprint as I can write mathematical expressions in my labels and with a simple command in LaTeX, I can change the size of the fonts easily. Also I can have the default LaTeX fonts in the labels.

Comment: see this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427573/saving-heavy-figure-to-pdf-in-matlab-rendering-problem

Answer (score 1):

Don't use eps. Use pdf format instead, and compile your LaTeX file with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see whether pdf or jpg would be more suitable. Pdf is still vector but if it's still some MB, then I'll simply make a pdf and then use Acrobat to capture the picture as a jpg. Yes I'll use pdflatex.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the render options painters or zbuffer help?

Does that mean that you're using OpenGL? If so, then what you're getting is a Postscript file which contains an image. Postscript is a good choice for vector images, but OpenGL can't generate vector images. If you really need the OpenGL renderer for something, then you might as well use a bitmap image format. If you really want to take advantage of EPS (or any other Postscript flavor), then you'll want to use Painters.

Comment: Thanks. I think that I'll go for jpg or pdf, whichever is smaller and run pdflatex. EPS is good for simple line diagrams but not where too many points are involved.